# How may I get the id from my chosen list in a different page ? Using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I am currently building a To Do List's website using PHP and MySQL.
I encountered a small problem about a foreign key that I cannot insert into my desired table.

My database is divided into three elements such as an user, a list and a task.
Basically, an unser got an id_user who can create any list. And these lists can have task in it.

A list is linked to the user with the foreign key `id_utilisateur`. And a task is bounded to a list with an `id_liste`. Therefore you cannot reach the list created from another user. Plus you cannot get the tasks with any of the lists created.

Here it's the deal.

I succeeded in the creation of a list with entering the foreign key `id_utilisateur` using `$_SESSION['id_utilisateur']`.

But when I created my task, I cannot reach the `id_liste` through the list chosen from the select objetc. I tried to do a `$_SESSION[id_liste]` but it doesn't work.

Here it is the code where I have the selected list :

```
<form action="VotreListe.php" method="POST">
    <SELECT name="ChoixDeVotreListe">
$idUtilisateurFK = $_SESSION['id_utilisateur'];
    $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT nom_liste FROM liste WHERE id_utilisateur = '$idUtilisateurFK'");
    //$reponse ->execute();
    //echo $reponse;
    while($data = $reponse->fetch())
    {
        ?>
        <option><?php echo $data['nom_liste']; ?>"</option>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </SELECT>
</form>
```

Then, here is the form for the creating of the task.

```
<div class ="ConteneurChampListe">
        <form action="VotreTache.php" method="post">
        <!-- Vérification des erreurs -->
        <?php include('errors.php'); ?>

        <div class="input-group">
        <label>Nom de votre tâche:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nomTache">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
        <label>Date de création de votre tâche:</label>
        <input id="datepicker" name="dateTache" type="date">
        </div>


        <div class="input-group">
        <label>Priorité de votre tâche:</label>
        <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="4" name="prioriteTache">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="bouton" name="creation_Tache">Créer</button>
        </div>           
        </form>
    </div>
```

If I create a task from this form, it will print the foreign key `id_liste` as `NULL`. Which is perfectly logical.

My question is simple :
How may I get the right `id_liste` in order to create a task with the `id_liste` as a foreign key ?

Here is the insert code :

```
$reqTache = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO tache (nom_tache, date_tache, priorite_tache, id_liste) 
        VALUES('$nomTache', '$dateTache', '$prioriteTache', '????')");
        $reqTache-> execute();
```

The ??? is the id_list from the select that i will use as a $variable.

Notice that all my SQL request codes are in another file such as server.php.

Thank you for you replies.

Comment: There's no opening `<select>` for your option and also your `<option>` has no value, you're just printing it

Comment: Sorry i dind't copy the entire code. the  <Select > exist. I will edit my thread

Comment: The more "important" part is that your `<option>` has no value

Comment: Allright, i will check that option value and test if it works with it. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to imagine how your tables structure is, but maybe you have to make `JOIN` in your query, like this:

```
SELECT nom_liste FROM liste INNER JOIN user USING (id_utilisateur)
WHERE id_utilisateur = '$idUtilisateurFK'
```

Comment: OK thank you i will try to add these lines. In fact, theses requests worked already like a charm. I am trying to make an INSERT INTO request with the task table using id_liste as a foreign key. But this id_liste as foreign key is always NULL.

Comment: I add it into the section edit. I think i find an idea ! I will test is asap.